# Select statement with a particular logic

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a **table** in **Microsoft Dynamics AX ERP** Database of **SQL Server 2008 R2**,  which has some rows, there is a field named qty in table, some rows have negative qty and some rows have positive quantity. There is another field TransactionID, now I want to select all those TransactionIDs which have negative qty, AND also those TransactionIDs which have some rows with positive QTys and negative qtys too.

TransactionID is a foreign key field of a master table.

So far I wrote below code which is not working.

```
select * from RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS main where main.qty < 0 
                                               and main.DATAAREAID = 'DAT'
and exists 
(
select 1 from RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS where QTY > 0 
and RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS.DATAAREAID = main.DATAAREAID
and RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS.STORE = main.STORE 
and RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS.TERMINALID = main.TERMINALID 
)

order by main.TRANSACTIONID
```

Comment: could you post table schema ? and what DBMS system is that ?

Comment: if you need some positive and some negative means you need both ie you dont need filtering rather straight select can do job, I guess

Comment: I need all negative, but positive with negatives, based on transactionIDs, like transaction number 1 has two negative rows, and transaction id 2 has one negative and one positive row, i want that too, but i dont want transaction 3 which has just 3 positive rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A recap, you want to select all rows for which there exists at least one row with the same TransactionID that has a negative quantity?

```
select * 
from RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS main 
where main.DATAAREAID = 'DAT'
 and exists 
  (
    select 1 
    from RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS sub 
    where sub.QTY < 0 
      and sub.DATAAREAID = main.DATAAREAID
      and sub.STORE = main.STORE 
      and sub.TERMINALID = main.TERMINALID
      and sub.TRANSACTIONID = main.TRANSACTIONID
  )
order by main.TRANSACTIONID
```

The main difference is, that you had a `main.QTY < 0` check. And I added `sub.TRANSACTIONID = main.TRANSACTIONID`.

Answer (score 1):

more or less the query should be like that

```
select * from 
(
select tansactionID, sum(qty) as q, sum(abs(qty)) as q2
from table2 T
group by tansactionID ) T
where q<> q2
```

post the schema so i can adjust it

Answer (score 1):

JOINed query defines `TRANSACTIONID` according your conditions (see `HAVING` conditions). So after JOIN you filter your table to leave only these `TRANSACTIONID`.

```
select t.* from RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS t
join
(
select TRANSACTIONID,min(main.qty),max(main.qty) 
    from RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS main 
GROUP BY TRANSACTIONID
HAVING (max(main.qty) < 0) 
         or 
       ((min(main.qty) < 0) and (max(main.qty) > 0))
) t1 on (t.TRANSACTIONID=t1.TRANSACTIONID)
```

**UPD** After you comment under your question I think you need to use only this condition in the inner query:

```
HAVING not (min(main.qty) < 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you may be over complicating the issue. If I am understanding the criteria correctly you want All rows where

- the quantity is < 0

**OR**

- the quantity is < 0 **AND** a row exists with the same transaction ID
  with a negative quantity

So to start

```
SELECT  *
FROM    RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS tr
WHERE   tr.DATAAREAID = 'DAT'
AND     tr.Qty < 0
```

Would satisfy the first criterion. The following would do the second.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS tr
WHERE   tr.DATAAREAID = 'DAT'
AND     tr.Qty > 0
AND     EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS neg
            WHERE   neg.TransactionID = tr.TransactionID
            AND     neg.DATAAREAID = 'DAT'
            AND     neg.Quantity < 0
        )
```

This can be combined as

```
SELECT  *
FROM    RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS tr
WHERE   tr.DATAAREAID = 'DAT'
AND (   tr.Qty < 0
    OR  EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS neg
            WHERE   neg.TransactionID = tr.TransactionID
            AND     neg.DATAAREAID = 'DAT'
            AND     neg.Quantity < 0
        )
    )
```

However, the first clause is redundant since any row where the quantity is `< 0` will also be satisfied by the `EXISTS` clause. So this can be simplified to:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS tr
WHERE   tr.DATAAREAID = 'DAT'
AND     EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    RBOTRANSACTIONSALESTRANS neg
            WHERE   neg.TransactionID = tr.TransactionID
            AND     neg.DATAAREAID = 'DAT'
            AND     neg.Quantity < 0
        )
```